# parameters with optional closures in swift

Tags: swift, parameters, closures, option-type

I'm using optional closures, but can't find a way to pass on a parameter.
Searched everywhere, tried all suggestions, but can't get it to work.

My code:

```
func DoAlert(title: String
    , message: String
    , actions: String
    , sender: AnyObject?
    , Ctlr : UIViewController
    , SegueString: String?
    , YesClosure: ()->() = {}
    , NoClosure: ()->() = {}
    , StartClosure: ()->() = {}
    , EndClosure: ()->() = {}
    ) {

if (actions.rangeOfString("Ok") != nil {
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default ) { action -> Void in
            EndClosure()
            })}
} // end function
```

I want to add a closure for Ok, where the 'self' parameter is needed.

Something like below:

```
    // add to func doAlert: 
    , OkClosure: (AnyObject)->() = {}


            // add to action Ok (before the EndClosure: 
            OkClosure(sender!)
```

Getting error on first line:
  AnyObject is not subtype of ()

If I leave AnyObject out of first line, Getting error:
  Cannot convert the expression's type 'AnyObject' to type '() => ()'

All other trials give me similar 'Tuple' errors.
How do I code the passing of parameters in the optional closures in my code?

Comment: A little nicer: `YesClosure: (() -> ())? = nil` and then use it like this: `YesClosure?()` (only runs if it is set). Also use lowerCaseCamelCasing for parameters, variables and instances.

Comment: `DoAlert` *might* have too many arguments.  There's no possible way to write clean code when you have a method that takes 10 arguments, made worse by the fact that four of them are closures.

Comment: nhgrif. I can see your view. DoAlert however is there to create clean code everywhere I want to simulate the VB "message box".

Comment: nhgrif. Therefore I can call the function with the fixed data (title, message etc), and have optional closures. Being optional, I can leave the closures out. So it might look 'non clean', when calling the function, it is so much cleaner than coding the Alert everywhere.  P.S. in having start alert and end alert, I can simply do functions at the start and after selecting, such as setting background colour according to severity (red for alert, green for msg). EndAlert resets it.

Comment: vrwim. Changed the closures as you suggested. Works exactly the same as the way I noted. suppose your way is more 'Swift like'  !!   In regard to the camelCasing, I have always used UpperCaseCamelCasing, not even knowing of a lowerCaseCamelCasing (and the apparent standards). I never programmed in C (where case seems to be important), and being a dinosaur, starting with Cobol I have  a habit of always starting UpperCamelling. Actually more used to underscore separation, but find Camelling better, now the words getting longer to be more explanatory.  In 'case sensitive' Swift, try to comply, !

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Firstly,** to use closures as an argument for a function, you should declare them like so:

```
func myFunc(closure: (Int) -> Void) {
    // Now I can call closure like so:
    let myInt = 10
    closure(myInt)
}
```

(As pointed out by @Airspeed Velocity, the parenthesis around `Int` are not strictly required because there is only one argument. Whether you include them is just personal preference)

**Secondly,** you can modify the previous function to include an optional closure, as follows:
(Note the `?` and parenthesis around the closure that indicate the closure is an optional, not the return type)

```
func myFunc(closure: ((Int) -> Void)?) {
    // Now when calling the closure you need to make sure it's not nil.
    // For example:
    closure?(10)
}
```

**Thirdly,** to add a default value of nil, which is what it looks like you're trying to do with the `= {}` on the end of `YesClosure: ()->() = {}`, you could do:

```
func myFunc(closure: ((Int) -> Void)? = nil) {
    // Still need to make sure it's not nil.
    if let c = closure {
        c(10)
    }
}
```

**Finally,** just as a note, you can set the names of the arguments of the closure, which can make it easier to identify what you're passing to the closure when calling it. For example:

(Note - here parenthesis are required around `value: Int`)

```
func myFunc(closure: ((value: Int) -> Void)) {
    closure(value: 10)
}
```

**Even more finally,** you could use `typealias`. According to the documentation:

> A type alias declaration introduces a named alias of an existing type into your program.

Here's an example of how to use it with a closure:

```
typealias MyClosureType = () -> Void

func myFunc(closure: MyClosureType) {
    closure()
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Nice answer! But one thing, when you say "When using closures as function arguments you need to make sure you enclose them in parenthesis”, you really don’t need to do this (IMHO it just adds clutter) unless you want to do something like mark the whole closure optional.

Comment: That's cool, I hadn't realised you could do that! I agree, not having extra parenthesis removes clutter. I will amend my answer accordingly.

Comment: You can also leave off the brackets around single arguments (i.e. `Int -> Void` instead of `(Int) -> Void`) though that’s more a personal preference thing (I prefer it).

Comment: ABakerSmith, Thanx for all the explanation. Still believe we are missing something. I am unable to call myfunc with the closure including the parameter.

Comment: What's the error you get? And what is parameter type for the argument in your closure?

Comment: I need to provide the Int value when calling func. So I tried to call as follows: myfunc (closure: theClosureToRun (11)) but it doesn't like it. In your sample, you provide the Int value in func, which is not what I need.

Comment: The error I get is: '()' is not convertible to 'Int -> Void'

Comment: Do you think you could post your whole function as an edit to you original question?

Comment: I think I found it. I can't use parameters in the closure when I call func. In func itself I need to pick up the variable, and add it to the closure call. O will show it as an answer, so you can comment.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found it. I can't use parameters in the closure when I call func. In func itself I need to define the parameters used (closure: (sender: AnyObject) -> Void), make sure the variables are defined (or provided as a separate parameter) and add them to the closure call.

```
@IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    myFunc (sender, doClosure)
}

func myFunc(sender: AnyObject, closure: (sender: AnyObject) -> Void) {
    // Now I can call closure like so:
    closure (sender: sender)
}

func doClosure(sender: AnyObject) {
    println("sender = \(sender)")
}
```